# upgrade wordpress 2.1.2 to wordpress latest version (3.6)

Tags: upgrade

I have wordpress 2.1.2 version website i want to upgrade the website into latest version of wordpress i:e 3.6.1.

i didn't find any solution in google, please let me know how to upgrade wordpress version from 2.1.2 to 3.6.1

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell that *should* be considerably straightforward, WP just couldn't update itself in versions that far back.

Codex has detailed instructions for upgrading from older versions, see [Upgrading WordPress Extended](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended#Detailed_Upgrade_Instructions_for_1.5.x.2C_and_versions_2.0_-_2.6.5.2C_to_3.6.1). However overall it's usual for manual update - backup, replace core files, go through upgrade dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

Usually upgrading WordPress version are easy and clean. But seeing the leap you are going to take please backup anything and everything before you go for the upgrade.

If the database structure is same like it is now, you can follow this link

http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress

Answer (score 1):

I would not jump from 2.1.2 to 3.6.1. That is a a high risk version change. I have seen severe problems with much smaller leaps.

My advice would be to [manually update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress) through at least the major revisions in the [Release Archive](http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/)-- 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, and so on. Painful, yes, but probably the safest path, and close to the one described in the Codex. [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended#Detailed_Upgrade_Instructions_for_1.5.x.2C_and_versions_2.0_-_2.6.5.2C_to_3.6.1) claims you can skip a single release but not more-- 2.1, 2.3, etc.

And of course, make a complete backup of everything before you begin-- files and database.